# Volley StringRequest not passing my parameters

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I need to post parameters to my server and it seems volley ignoring my parameters and give me null values

here is my code:

```
      StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("from", textfrom_btn);
                            params.put("to", textto_btn);
                            params.put("seat", seat);

                            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
                            return params;
                        }

                    };

                    // Adding request to request queue
                    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

the response always give empty array and server sent message to me that my $_POST["from"] and so on are null

I pass the value from another activity to this activity, and here how I got the value...
first I declare String:

```
String textfrom, textto, seat
```

then get value from another activity via intent

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
        if (extras.hasExtra("page")) {
            String value = extras.getStringExtra("page");
            if(value.equals("search")) {
                textfrom_btn = extras.getStringExtra("from");
                textto_btn = extras.getStringExtra("to");
                seat = extras.getStringExtra("seat");

            }
        }
```

and volley StringRequest code after that...

Comment: What is your output of `Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());` ?

Comment: Check URL is correct or not.

Comment: E/Searching: Posting params: {to=SAG, seat=1, from=PTK}, my url is fine because when I delete one of my param it sent me msg_error from server

Comment: can you post your php  code

Comment: Hi, @Jois you can go to my previous [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277467/volley-not-passing-any-parameters-in-jsonarrayrequest) for php code

Comment: @I_Droid how I do that?

Comment: just simply hard code some really value and pass it.you can then identify that params values are non null

Comment: when I hard coded it, it pass all the value I need, so it means my variables are empty....thanks

Comment: so new question arise, why my variables didn't have value although my Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString()); has the value from my variables

Comment: How do you get the value from variable and pass into params?Post your code where you obtaining the value

Comment: @I_Droid, Hi, check my updated post...thanks

Comment: You params are still empty???

Comment: Ya I got that what might be problem. Intent keys value may be null so you can check intent is null or not. Also, you can use default value for string [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408419/how-do-i-tell-if-intent-extras-exist-in-android)

Comment: still not working, is there any alternative how I should do...

Comment: Use Logcat to check you received same value sent from another activity before use that value in params

Comment: thanks, because of you I know where I'm wrong...there are wrong value in my database...thanks :)